# Extract content in the cell of a table in a Word document using POI Java

Tags: java, text, apache-poi, extract

I have been using Java and POI to extract data from Word documents (docx). Basically I want to extract data contained in a two column table. I want the program to distinguish between the left and right columns and store the various values in an array the thing is that it extracts the text row by row:

```
table.getText()
```

I used this method but it doesn't distinguish between the cells. It just grab all the text from a  row.

The code I used can be found [here](http://www.concretepage.com/apache-api/apache-poi-xwpf-read-ms-word-docx-header-footer-paragraph-table-example)

I couldn't find a method to extract the text in each cell

Comment: So did you try retrieving the rows, then from each row retrieve a cell, then from that cell retrieve the text? The Javadocs are here: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html

Comment: If you give us some code to look at, we might be able/willing to help more.

Comment: Ok I edited my question.
I browsed the doc I couldn't find a method that would extract the text in a cell. I tinkered with all the methods and it didn't return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the javadocs at https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html, I would try something like:

```
table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getText();
```

You might want to put it in a loop to retrieve the text in each row on it's own. None of these things is iterable though, so you will have to use a for loop to retrieve the data. The integer in `getRow()` and `getCell()` is a zero based index to the table row and cell.

When you look at the javadocs, the classes are all in `org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel`. If you want to dig deeper, you will need to get the source.